# How can I fetch rows using Docrine2 in a ManytoOne relationship

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have the following tables, where I have no problem in inserting, updating etc. But, how can I fetch the result rows for this kind of mapping?

```
Organizations
-->id
-->name

users
-->id
-->first_name

doctors
-->id
-->user_id


org_doctors
-->id
-->org_id
-->doctor_id
```

This is my OrgDoctor Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Doctor\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;
use User\Entity\User;
use Doctor\Entity\Doctor;
use Organization\Entity\Organization;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="org_doctors")
 */
class OrgDoctor extends BaseEntity{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctor\Entity\Doctor", inversedBy="orgDoctor")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="doctor_id",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
     */
    protected $doctor;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organization\Entity\Organization", inversedBy="orgDoctor")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="org_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $organization;

    public function setDoctor(Doctor $doctor = null)
    {
        $this->doctor = $doctor;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDoctor()
    {
        return $this->doctor;
    } 

    public function setOrganization(Organization $organization = null)
    {
        $this->organization = $organization;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOrganization()
    {
        return $this->organization;
    }    
}
```

And this is my Doctor Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Doctor\Entity;

use Library\Entity\BaseEntity;
use Users\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="doctors")
 */
class Doctor extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Users\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @var Users\Entity\User
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="summary", type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    private $summary;

    function getUser() {
        return $this->user;
    }

    function setUser(User $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

     function getSummary() {
        return $this->summary;
    }

    function setSummary($summary) {
        $this->summary = $summary;
    }
}
```

This is how I'm fetching the result for a single doctor:

```
$doctor = $this->entityManager->find('Doctor\Entity\Doctor', (int) $doctorId);
```

How can I fetch rows from the OrgDoctor entity?

this is how i tried using queryBuilder:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('od', 'd', 'o')
            ->from('Doctor\Entity\OrgDoctor', 'od')
            ->join('od.organization', 'o')
            ->join('od.doctor', 'd')
            ->where('od.organization = :organization')
            ->setParameter('organization', $orgId);
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $results =  $query->getResult();
        var_dump($results);

 Notice: Undefined index: orgDoctor in C:\xampp\htdocs\corporate-wellness\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 125
```

In Organization Entity:

```
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Doctor\Entity\OrgDoctor", mappedBy="organization")
     */
    protected $orgDoctor;
```

Comment: add bidirectional relation doc 1<-->* org_doc and get all doc org $doc->getOrgdocts()  //(ArrayCollection)

Comment: Why do you need the entity OrgDoctor at all? It does not contain any other property than the two entities that is linking together.

Comment: @hasumedic I have the extra columns, extra columns was in the  BaseEntity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your entity mapping, Doctrine should provide you with an out of the box repository for your OrgDoctor entity. That repository implements a few methods for you to retrieve entities of that type. One of them is `findBy`, which return arrays of OrgDoctor entities:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(OrgDoctor::class)->findBy(['doctor' => $doctorId]));

$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(OrgDoctor::class)->findBy(['organization' => $organizationId]));

$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(OrgDoctor::class)->findBy(['doctor' => $doctorId, 'organization' => $organizationId]));
```

The last example, would be quite similar to `findOneBy`, which would return an OrgDoctor entity instead of an array:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository(OrgDoctor::class)->findOneBy(['doctor' => $doctorId, 'organization' => $organizationId]));
```

If you're planning to loop through the results and access their properties or other relationships, you might want to change the default repository strategy and define a [custom repository](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) for your OrgDoctor entity. What this will allow you to do, is to write your custom queries for retrieving your entities by means of a query builder class and DQL.

In order to avoid [N+1 problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97253/1768811), you want to fetch join before a loop to fetch all the necessary associations in one go, so you won't be running N queries within your loop:

```
$qb->select('od', 'd', 'o')
   ->from(OrgDoctor::class, 'od')
   ->join('od.organization', 'o')
   ->join('od.doctor', 'd')
   ->where('od.doctor = :doctor')
   ->setParameter('doctor', $doctorId)
;
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it only return the org_id and doctor_id and remaining objects return as null. that means shall i need to once again findBy(doctorId) in the Doctor Entity and find(orgId) in Org Entity

Comment: What do you mean that they return org_id and doctor_id? They should return either an OrgDoctor array (findBy) or an OrgDoctor object (findOneBy). Once the entity is hydrated, you should be able to do $organizationDoctor->getDoctor() and $organizationDoctor->getOrganization() to obtain the objects. The ORM will do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: As you said, if i use $organizationDoctor->getDoctor() and $organizationDoctor->getOrganization() to obtain the objects, wont it be heavy for me.

Comment: Wont it be heavy lifting for me,    if i do like this, $orgDoctors =  $this->entityManager->getRepository('Doctor\Entity\OrgDoctor')
->findBy(['organization' => $orgId]);

//returns 200 rows od data
$resArr =  array();
foreach($orgDoctors as $doc) { 
 $resArr = array (
  'orgName' => $doc->getOrganization()->getName(),
  'doctorId' => $doc->getDoctor()->getId(),
  'doctorName' => $doc->getDoctor()->getName(),
  
 );
        
}

Comment: @haumedic Do i need to use, any left join, this is my raw sql --> SELECT 
        od.org_id,
        od.doctor_id,
        od.is_active as orgDoctorIsActive,
        d.user_id,
        u.first_name as firstName,
        u.last_name as lastName,
        u.email_id as emailId,
        u.contact_number as contactNumber
        FROM 
        org_doctors od
        LEFT JOIN  doctors d ON od.doctor_id = d.id 
        LEFT JOIN users u ON d.user_id = u.id WHERE od.org_id = 1

Comment: You can do left joins if you want, but I doubt that you'd have OrgDoctor entities without a Doctor or an Organization.

Comment: Thanks for the support, $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('od', 'd', 'o')
            ->from('Doctor\Entity\OrgDoctor', 'od')
            ->join('od.organization', 'o')
            ->join('od.doctor', 'd')
            ->where('od.organization = :organization')
            ->setParameter('organization', $orgId);
        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        $results =  $query->getResult();
        var_dump($results);
        exit;

Comment: I am getting the following error for the above comment... Notice: Undefined index: orgDoctor in C:\xampp\htdocs\corporate-wellness\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 125

Comment: That's because your relationships are not properly defined. There's no "orgDoctor" inversedBy relationship in your Doctor or Organization entities. But that's outside of the scope of what your original question was.

Comment: /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Doctor\Entity\OrgDoctor", mappedBy="organization")
     */
    protected $orgDoctor; //In Organization Entity

Comment: Thanks man, its works like a charm now, I forgot to add a inverse relationship in Doctor Entity.

Comment: Glad it's working. You might consider up-voting and accepting the answer then ;)